# Can I get the 'Enough Coin to Disappear' achievement with a high chaos save from Knife of Dunwall DLC?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

I want to get the [Enough Coin to Disappear achievement](http://www.trueachievements.com/a178089/enough-coin-to-disappear-achievement.htm) for the new The Brigmore Witches DLC. To make it easier, I am going to import a save from the previous DLC - The Knife of Dunwall. One of the requirements of the achievement is to obtain the required amount of coins *in low chaos*. Does this mean the save I import from KoD also have to be done in low chaos or does the low chaos requirement only apply to the levels in the new DLC?

Comment: I would guess the achievement is awarded at the end of the campaign, and you must have a low chaos rating. Importing a save with a high chaos would start you at a disadvantage if you're shooting for the achievement. I'm not sure if it's possible to start with high and end with low (there may not be enough events to completely negate all your accumulated chaos) but if it is it will probably be difficult.

Comment: @Jason_c_o Actually after playing it, I found it's impossible to even start a low chaos game with a high chaos. So the answer is you have to have a low chaos save from Knife of Dunwall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You cannot. It's impossible to even start a low chaos game with a high chaos save.